# Processing Custom Alexa Skill Cards in AVS-SDK

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am building some simple custom skills with card like this:

`this.response.cardRenderer(skillName,textCard);
this.emit(':responseReady');`

I have AVS SDK installed on a Raspberry Pi, but I can't see where the card info ends up. The service simulator has the following info in the service response:

```
  "card": {
    "content": "hum, I can't sense any fan here.",
    "title": "FanControlIntent on"
  },
```

Is there anyway I can extract the card info so I can process it in the SDK on my raspberry pi? My first guess is this will be in the payload of the directive but is not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on amazon developer forum, Card data is not exposed in any API at the moment. See the following ref.

- https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/67919/how-do-i-access-the-alexa-card-responses-on-my-ras.html
- https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/63071/display-alexa-card-information.html